# TRX Logger not available on azure roles

Tags: testing, logging, azure

I am trying to run tests on azure roles with the vstest.console.exe test runner. It is working great on emulator but in the real azure cloud instance the TRX-Logger I want to use is not available.

I am copying the hole test Runner Folder to my cloud instance with all the DLL files and dependencies which are in subfolders of the "...\TestWindow\" folder. There is also a dll-file for the TfsLogger, as well as the dll-file for the TrxLogger. But when I run vstest.console.exe it states that /logger:trx option is invalid because trx is not a valid URI or friendly name. When I list all available loggers for vstest.console.exe I only get the 2 test loggers "Console" and "TfsLogger" (or "TfsPublisher").

This is the Content of my Extensions Folder:

```
E:\approot\TestRunner\Extensions\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.dll
E:\approot\TestRunner\Extensions\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.GenericTestAdapter.dll
E:\approot\TestRunner\Extensions\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.MSAppContainerAdapter.dll
E:\approot\TestRunner\Extensions\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.OrderedTestAdapter.dll
E:\approot\TestRunner\Extensions\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.TfsLogger.dll
E:\approot\TestRunner\Extensions\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.TmiAdapter.dll
E:\approot\TestRunner\Extensions\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.TrxLogger.dll
E:\approot\TestRunner\Extensions\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.VSTestIntegration.dll
E:\approot\TestRunner\Extensions\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.UnitTestFramework.dll
E:\approot\TestRunner\Extensions\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.CppUnitTestFramework.ComInterfaces.dll
E:\approot\TestRunner\Extensions\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.CppUnitTestFramework.CppUnitTestExtension.dll;
```

Does anybody know why trx logger is not available on the azure instances (worker role) but TfsLogger is, while both dll files are available in the same subfolder of vstest.console.exe? And is it possible to "install" or make the TrxLogger available for my test runner?!

Best regards

Sebastian

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but I just faced a similar problem where I only had Console & TfsLogger, but no way to have the TrxLogger.
The difference being that I'm not using Azure, I'm on my CI test server on which I only installed MSBuild 2013, as part of the new "Microsoft Build Tools Package".
It installed everything, but I wasn't able to have the TrxLogger for MSBuild VS 2013, whereas it was working fine for VS 2012.

After some search, I enabled logging for vstest.console (by setting the TpTraceLevel to 4 from its config file), and it logged some info inside my Local Temp folder.

Only to see that it failed trying to load the TrxLogger assembly (sorry for the French messages :)):

```
W, 3384, 1, 2014/03/07, 10:46:08.269, 2034438793, vstest.console.exe, TestPluginDiscoverer: Failed to get types from assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.TrxLogger, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.  Skipping test extension scan for this assembly.  Error: System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Impossible de charger un ou plusieurs des types requis. Extrayez la propriété LoaderExceptions pour plus d'informations.
   à System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
   à System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes()
   à System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
   à Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Core.TestPluginsFramework.TestPluginDiscoverer.GetTestExtensionsFromAssembly(Assembly assembly, Dictionary`2 testDiscoverers, Dictionary`2 testExecutors, Dictionary`2 testSettingsProviders, Dictionary`2 testLoggers)

W, 3384, 1, 2014/03/07, 10:46:08.269, 2034439310, vstest.console.exe, LoaderExceptions: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Impossible de charger le fichier ou l'assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Common, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' ou une de ses dépendances. Le fichier spécifié est introuvable.
Nom de fichier : 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Common, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
   à System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   à System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   à System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   à System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef)
   à Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Core.TestPluginsFramework.TestPluginCache.CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(Object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
   à System.AppDomain.OnAssemblyResolveEvent(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String assemblyFullName)
```

For simplification, what I ended up doing was to install the whole Visual Studio 2013 on my server, but as the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Common` assembly was available in my ReferenceAssemblies folder, maybe I just needed some way to reference it (add to path or something)

Comment: For me it was enough to put `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Common` to the same folder with VSTest.console.exe.